# Recycle App Pool after 15 minutes upon deployment by jenkins

Tags: asp.net, powershell, jenkins

I do deployment to `Server 1` via Jenkins. Now, DFS would sync it to other servers in about 15 minutes. How do I automatically recycle `app pools` at each server once the DFS has synced to it.

FYI: I can't wait for 15 minutes and keep the current jenkins job at hold and then recycle because I have to do multiple jenkins jobs.

FYI: I require DFS replication because we add pages dynamically at server via website which should be available at all servers. And we know there is no way to do this without DFS.

Comment: Curious why you are using DFS-R if you have automated deployment? My first thought is that you should disable replication and use Jenkins to deploy to each server individually, then each job can restart the app pool on each machine. If there's a reason you need replication please edit it into your question to clarify.

Comment: @briantist: Updated Question

Comment: It may not be the answer you're looking for, but I think restructuring may be best. It will be messy to trigger a service restart on a change of multiple files from DFS-R. You might consider making the storage of dynamic pages/user uploads separate (not included in the real directory tree of the application) then use virtual directories in IIS to point there. DFS-R can replicate that separate storage, meanwhile the rest of the application gets deployed via deployment process. I think this adds a lot in terms of flexibility and reliability of your deploys.